# I'm trying to drop cells in a Pandas Dataframe that contain countless spaces

Tags: python, pandas, replace

When importing from a certain log file, I get a pandas dataframe containing cells with strings (including spaces) separated by cells that contain many and only spaces that seem to change in count without pattern. I need to drop these cells without removing the spaces in the cells that containing strings.

I've already tried replacing these seemingly empty cells with NaN with replace(' ', np.NaN, inplace = True). And get only Nonetype cells.

Some example of my Dataframe:

```
22  96069fb0-f0c9-4754-bfdf...
23                                                  
24  9eg95e03-da49-453a-a0d4...
25
```

What I need to get to:

```
22  96069fb0-f0c9-4754-bfdf...
23  9eg95e03-da49-453a-a0d4...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, though probably not the most efficient:

```
df = df[df.col_name.str.strip().str.len()>0]
```

where `col_name` is, of course, the name of the relevant column.